# Mock objects which are initialized in the method itself

Tags: junit, mockito

Is there any way to mock objects which are initialized in the method itself. For example

```
void myMethod(){
    SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();
    int count = sample.getProductCount(5L);
}
```

I want to mock getProductCount method something like

```
when(sample.getProductCount(any(Long.class)).thenReturn(10)
```

But I don't find a way to do so. Any advice?

Comment: You would need to extract that tight coupling out into an abstraction and explicitly inject it into the dependent class.

Comment: Nikosi any help source ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [@Spy](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Spy.html) which lets you mock specific method,

> A field annotated with @Spy can be initialized explicitly at declaration point.

In your case prepare the spy:

```
@Spy
private SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();

@BeforeMethod
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

And in test:

```
doReturn(10).when(sample).getProductCount(any(Long.class));
```